# How to get below output using awk or sed or using any other option

Tags: sed, awk

this is the data file I have and I want below output
How can I achieve it.

```
07:15:01 ST go-b-s1
07:15:21 FA go-b-s1
07:15:22 FA go-a-s1
07:15:01 ST go-c-s2
07:15:21 FA go-c-s2

output

how to get below output using awk or sed

07:15:01 ST go-b-s1 07:15:21 FA go-b-s1
07:15:22 FA go-a-s1
07:15:01 ST go-c-s2 07:15:21 FA go-c-s2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just want to trim the newline from lines that have `ST` in the second column.  If that's the case:

```
awk '$2 == "ST" { printf "%s ", $0; next} 1' input-file
```

Other options:

```
sed '/ST/{ N; s/\n/ /; }' input-file
perl -pe 's/\n/ / if /ST/' input-file
```

It's difficult to tell what you actually want with just one sample.  It is generally a good idea to at least attempt to describe how you want to manipulate the data.